# Javascript setting a function to a function with a parameter

Tags: javascript, function, object, parameters

I'm trying to set an object's "touched" function to another function. I hear about JavaScript and first class functions all the time but still don't have the hang of it. Here's what I have:

```
customClose.touched = this._close.bind(this);
```

customClose has a function called "touched" that is empty by default. I want it to be set to another function, this._close.bind, which takes a parameter. How can I make this work?

Answer (score 0):

This will do the trick:

```
customClose.touched = this._close.bind;
```

Note that if you use `this` inside of `this._close.bind`, when calling `customClose.touched(p)`, `this` will refer to `customClose`.

If you want `this` to continue referring to `this._close`, you can use [`bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind):

```
customClose.touched = this._close.bind.bind(this._close);
```

Comment: I just found out the problem was something else entirely. My original line works fine. I think my kind of confusing problem and explanation led to your somewhat verbose answer, but I think you were on the right track if there were actually a problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It turns out my original implementation was correct. The problem was that the close button had moved due to another change I had made. Since it's invisible, I didn't notice. Binding the function to the object's function is done as follows:

```
customClose.touched = this._close.bind;
```